# Check if string zero, zero, empty string, null

Tags: javascript, jquery

in PHP:

```
$var=0;
$var="";
$var="0";
$var=NULL;
```

to verify if $var is 0 or "0" or "" or NULL

```
if (!$var) {...}
```

in jQuery/JavaScript:

```
$var=0;
$var="";
$var="0";
$var=NULL;
```

`if (!$var)` works for every value except for "0"

Is there a general way in JavaScript/jQuery to check all kinds of those empty/null/zero values, exactly like php does?

Comment: Don't rely on this confusing type castings. Use explicit strict checks with `===`.

Comment: What if the string isn't empty, but only has space characters? If you include those, then you can convert the value to a number. All of those will end up as `0`... `if (+my_var === 0) {`

Comment: If this is really your case why don't you just check for `!value || value == '0'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a general way in JavaScript/jQuery to check all kinds of those empty/null/zero values, exactly like php does?

No. In PHP, the values converted to booleans produces different results than in JavaScript. So you can't do it *exactly* like PHP does.

Why not be (a bit more) explicitly about it which makes your code easier to understand?

```
// falsy value (null, undefined, 0, "", false, NaN) OR "0"
if (!val || val === '0') { }
```

Comment: I first answered `!+v` but it's not reliable the other way around: [example](http://jsbin.com/kedija/2/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Felix: based on your answer:function is_empty(myvar) {var res=false; if (!myvar || myvar==='0') res=true; return res; }

Comment: This solution with === does not provide sufficient coverage. if val = "00", it will return true instead of false.

Answer (score 6):

Number(variable) seems to produce expected output

```
Number(0) = 0
Number("0") = 0
Number("") = 0
Number(null) = 0
Number(false) = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

The abstract operation ToBoolean converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 11:

> **Undefined** false
>       **Null** false
>       **Boolean** The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
>       **Number** The result is false if the argument is +0, -0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.
>       **String** The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero);
>       otherwise the result is true.
>       **Object** true

0 will return false.

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: thanks, I noticed that, but I am looking for a general way to check it in JS like php does.

Comment: the way you did in php.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel *funky* (just in your exact case-sample) you can do this:
*(otherwise `undefined` and `NaN` will result as `false`)*

```
+v===0
```

Example:

```
var a = [0, "",  "0", null];
var b = [1, "a", "1", {}];

a.forEach(function(v){
  console.log( +v===0 ); // true, true, true, true
});

b.forEach(function(v){
  console.log( +v===0 ); // false, false, false, false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of "0" isn't false, its true. Because '0' is a string. Strings if they exist return true. So 
!"" should return false. That said if your data is returning zeros as strings you can use:

```
parseInt("0", 10);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

This will return the integer value or NaN.
!NaN will return true, and if it is an number of say... 0 it will return !0 so you could do this:

```
function nullOrEmpty(value) {
    return (!value && !parseInt(value));
}
```

Comment: `parseInt` not `Parse.Int`

Comment: *"Strings if they exist return true. So !"" should return false."* That's not correct. `!""` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You could very well use a double negative.

```
var test = 0;
console.log(!!test);

var test = "";
console.log(!!test);

var test = "0";
console.log(!!test);

var test = null;
console.log(!!test);
```

Although `"0"` is not an empty string so it evaluates to true, the rest return false.

Also, I agree with the comment that dfsq made in that you shouldn't rely on this. You should know and understand what types your variables are holding.